# Why mongoose populate return me an illegal array and how to do with it?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I use mongoose populate a list of data like:

```
 Account.findOne({_id:accountId}).populate({
            path:"orders.order",
            match:{_id:orderId},
            selecte:'',
            options:{
              limit:1
            }
          }).exec(function (err, doc) {
              if (err) {
                callback(err);
              }
              callback(doc);
          })
        }
```

and what I get:

```
[ { order: null },
  { order: null },
  { order: null },
  { order: null },
  { order: null },
  { order: null },
  { order: 
     { date: Tue May 31 2016 12:56:36 GMT+0800 (HKT),
       dishs: [Object],
       __v: 0,
       message: 'plz deliver after 5 p.m',
       price: 5,
       address: [Object],
       shop: null,
       user: 574bfebc29cf722c17f8eafe,
       _id: 574d198451615ce01a5e1a81 } } ]
```

I think this data is an array, but

```
                console.log(typeof doc.orders);//object
                console.log(doc.orders.length);//undefined
                console.log(doc.orders[0].order);//error
                console.log(Array.isArray(doc.orders));//false
```

I do not know how to delete null value of this data and how to change this data into an array?

By the way, I find a post in gist said that mongoose populate.match will return null value if it did not match the condition, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make mistake that I define the schema the wrong way.

**The wrong schema:**

```
orders:{order: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Order'}] }
```

The right way the define schema in array which you what to populate:

```
orders:{type:[{
  order:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Order'}
}]}
```

After this, use populate.match will give you an legal array and your could do with it like normal array.